# How to create small text aligned center and below icon in Bootstrap 4 navbar nav-item without affecting navbar height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I have a navbar with the following nav-item:

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <a> <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Option A</a>
      </form>
```

I want to add small text aligned center and below the icon. What is the best way to do this? (The Option A text should be big enough to be legible, but not big enough that the navbar bootstrap classes need to be modified to accommodate)

Note: I want to make sure both the text and the icon are vertically aligned in the middle of the navbar without increasing the navbar's height, which pt-3 or mt-3 on the "a" appears to affect.

Adding a `<p>` also appears to have made the navbar "taller"... which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to wrap it in a `<small>` element and add the `d-block` class to the icon. Then, everything is wrapped in a `<span>` with the classes `navbar-nav text-center pt-1 pb-0` to center both and vertically align them in the middle of the navbar. The classes `nav-item nav-link p-0` on the anchor tag turn it into a nav link and remove the padding:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="navbar-nav text-center pt-1 pb-0">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link p-0"><small><i class="fa fa-gear d-block"></i>Option A</small></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

did not tested but put option a in to `<p>` tag

```
 <form class="form-inline">
            <a> <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <p>Option A</p></a>
        </form>
```

Comment: This is very close, but the icon is not positioned in the center of the wording and it appears the text and icon are vertically not center aligned on the navbar. Attempts to put "pt-3" or "mt-3" class helps with alignment, but at the expense of the size of the navbar. I want to shift both the icon and the center aligned text down on the navbar, but no expanding the navbar's height.

Comment: Dude make fiddle @Rolando